# Target class [Backend\App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have the following controller: `ProductController` which is located in `App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController.php` and the following route

```
Route::resource('product','App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController');
```

For some reason , it gives me the error provided in the title, I really don't understand why since I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right-click</kbd> on the route and it redirects me to the very controller.

I also tried:

```
Route::resource('product',App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController::class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example will work if you put your Product Controller in the App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ folder.

```
Route::resource('product', App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController::class);
```

That will give you the following methods: index, store, create, show, update, destroy, and edit.

Comment: it is located in the backend folder

Comment: Are there any product routes at all? Try php artisan route:cache && php artisan route:list

Comment: ```Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [Backend\App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController] does not
 exist.

  at E:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\lapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Conta
iner\Container.php:832
    828▕
    829▕         try {
    830▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    831▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 832▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concre
te] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    833▕         }
    834▕```

after executing php route:list

Comment: It is looking for the following controller (notice the two "Backends" in your path): Backend\App\Http\Controllers\Backend\ProductController.

Comment: The thing is that i don't have this first backend folder .

Comment: That makes sense that you are getting that error then. Perhaps review your routes in web.php.

Comment: yes thank you , i solved it , i forgot i had a route:group with the namespace backend there

Comment: Wonderful. Can you please "accept" my answer?